# Polymer implement native select element

Tags: select, polymer, native, element

I'm implementing a polymer custom element using a native select with options.

```
<select id="selectbox" value="{{selectedId::change}}">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{arrayItems}}" >
    <option value="{{item}}" id="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
  </template>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fiddle_gabriela/a58L52yh/2/

The `selectedId` represents the id of the item to be selected in the select box
(1 for the first element, 2 for the second, etc.).

At the creation of the select box I would like to select the 4th element in the list.
The problem is that `selectedId` gets the value of the element (e.g. admission, alert, ...) and not its id.

How to get the id instead of the value?

**update** expected result (from comment)

```
<select> 
  <option value="admission">admission</option> 
  <option value="alert">alert</option> 
  <option value="bvt_sample">bvt_sample</option> 
  <option value="clinicalpath" selected > clinicalpath</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to check if the current item is the same as the one actually selected.

```
<option value="{{item}}" id="{{item}}" selected="{{isSelected(item)}}">
```

```
isSelected: function(item) {
  console.log(item);
    return item === this.selectedId;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zkrb4jkz/

Comment: actually the issue is that I cannot link the selectedId with the selected option.       <select>
  <option value="admission">admission</option>
  <option value="alert">alert</option>
  <option value="bvt_sample">bvt_sample</option>
  <option value="clinicalpath"  selected > clinicalpath</option>
</select>

Comment: Link how? Link where?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the above result, but using a dom-repeat on my array.  (sorry, I couldn't indent the code)

Comment: So you want the selected attribute being added to the selected `<option>`?

Comment: yes :)  The problem is that dom-repeat creates a template for every option and there is no way to pass the selectedId.  (I already tried with jquery and javascript).

Comment: Great :) If this answers your question please accept it by clicking the checkmark  below the up/down-vote buttons to indicate your question is answered. Thanks!